# Cross origin framing Google VR

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to use the VR viewer from Google that you can find here:
https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview

Setup is pretty easy, no issue with this but I'm now having a cross origin framing issue on my own site. Here is an example:
http://laurentwillen.be/flat_files/vr.php

There I call the JS file and the JPG file from the same domain and same directory on the server but I still get this in my console:
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://www.laurentwillen.be/flat_files/index.html?image=http://www.laurentwillen.be/flat_files/VR/catane.jpg does not permit cross-origin framing.

I see here that the error refers to a html file that doesn't exist. Should I modify something in my htaccess file ?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 1):

The html file it is looking for ( index.html ) is part of the embed api.  In the default setup for vrview, it is served from /

for example, here is the online demo root folder: http://googlevr.github.io/vrview/

(it will just show you an error atm, because you don't load it directly)

that directory (or some other you set up, i like to use /embed ) must serve that index page and its needed parts. (in /build and /images )

The examples are served from /examples, but the other directories are needed for the api to work.

Comment: Hi Tommy, thanks. I tried the package from github on my local machine and it works fine but if I upload the same package to my server, I get an error message: Forbidden...You don't have permission to access ...

Comment: test url is here: http://www.laurentwillen.be/flat_files/vr_package/examples/gallery/index.html

Comment: ok, I have understood the issue, my htaccess is protecting me from file injection but this is exactly what this script is trying to do. I know need to find a way to avoid this. I'm wondering why the script in the cloud cannot solve this :(